# How two know when a maven project has the same transitive dependenciy twice of different versions?

Tags: maven

I have to add a new dependency to a maven project. This dependency has four transitive dependencies(according to http://mvnrepository.com/) and between them, there is spring-data-jpa jar.

The maven project I am working in has many dependencies configured in the pom so I understand there could be a big possibility that there is already a spring-data-jpa dependency in the project(transitive or not).

1. When you work in a large project with many dependencies and you have to add a new one, how to check if there is already the same transitive dependency of a different version? I have to check manually the transitive dependencies for each direct dependency configured? Has maven a warning for this situation?
2. How maven works in this situation? I mean, there could be two spring-data-jpa jars of different versions(this would be a problem) or maven resolves this in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that the dependency plugin can tell you. The longer answer is that there are a number of different situations to consider about transitive dependency management, and how the plugin helps and what to do about it differs for each one.

Maven automatically chooses which dependency to include if two dependencies have the same coordinates (groupId, artifactId) with different versions. Broadly speaking, it picks the version that's highest in the tree - effectively overriding dependencies defined in downstream transitive dependency poms. So, if you have two different versions of exactly the same dependency then you will still only find one version of the dependency on the relevant classpath.

The dependency plugin can help you identify this situation by highlighting points where its made a decision, but you probably want to use the *dependencyManagement* section of your top-level pom to ensure that the dependencies which you bring in are the ones you expect.

Separate difficulties can arise when a dependency changes its groupId or artifactId. Then you can get two dependencies on the classpath - one with an old version on the old coordinates and one with the new version on the new coordinates. As examples, Spring, Hibernate and Apache commons have all found themselves doing this at some point or another. In this case all you can do is use to the dependency plugin to identify duplicated dependencies and then use *exclusions* tags to explicitly exclude them as transitive dependencies from the dependencies which are pull them in.

It's important to note that all of this dependency management can cause unintended breakage. If the thing that your application depends on really does depend on some specific version of a package as a transitive dependency then you can break it by overriding that version. So testing the features that you use is essential.

Comment: Ok, thanks, although one situation might happen when maven selects the artifactory with the highest version, and is that if one method in the old artifactory was deprecated and it was being called in your code, selecting maven the highest version of this artifactory, this method could not be present but you would get an inmediate compiling error so it would be easy to see this situation

Comment: When taking the case that the groupId or artifactId is changed, any tools can find them? We have issues when using XML jards, and it is cause we are using two jars by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)? There's some useful goals you can run, such as `mvn dependency:tree` etc.